# Angular-ui-grid : Focus a specific cell of the selected row.

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have the following code:

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row){
      console.log(row);
})
```

This will bring me the selected row in the grid, and will be highlighted, I ma good so far, but once there I would like to focus a specific  cell to be edited, to eventually use the event "`gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow`" to save the changes. How I can archive that ?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple example of your code in JSFiddle might give us a chance to help you solve this.

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle? Also, why is $scope passed into the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use row state, in your case, the selected row row.

- clean -no edit have been made
- isDirty - edit has been made, but the date is not saved yet
- isSaving - it is saving your data. Callback is not returned yet
- isError - the save callback returned an error.

To check whether you have something to save on the row. Then you can use

```
$scope.saveRow = function (rowEntity){
     //create your promise that will eventually save your data.
     //return success/error
};    
gridApi.rowEdit.on.saveRow($scope,  $scope.saveRow)
```

to save your changes. Have a look at this plunker (from ui.grid tutorial) [Row Edit](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2ZpFs6ikdmscN3YFiW7?p=preview).

I did not get what you meant by "focus a specific cell to be edited".

Best